# View filter on created by me doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, view

I try to create a view in a document library which must display to the user only his documents, when I filter the view on created by= [me] it gives nothing, I have no document displayed knowing that I use sharepoint in French and so I used created by [moi] I also tried in English [me] but the same

Comment: Hi, have you tried the value as [Me] ('M' upper case)?

Comment: Check if you have any other filters on the view, that is, start with "AlItems". I have just verified in SP-online, "Created By=[Me] or Created By =[me] and found out either should work

Comment: I try it, but it doesn't work, i don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found solution, in reality i should use [Utilisateur actif]  instead of [Me], now it's work

Answer (score 0):

When you want to display your own documents in the view, Created By = [Me] and Created By = [me] both work.

When you want to create a view in a document library to display the document created by himself, you should use Created by = his account name.

The formula Created By = [Me] only works on filter a column based on the current user of the site.

Comment: I want that each user see only his document, so i should use Create By= [Me] i don't undurstand  why it doesn't work

Comment: Create By = [Me] only works for the current user.
For example, when you login SharePoint Online with your account, Create By = [Me] has the effect on displaying the files you have created and it has no effect on other users.